# Difference between onStart() and onResume()

Tags: android

I can't get the meaning of `onStart()` transition state. The `onResume()` method is always called after `onStart()`. Why can't it be the `onResume()` is invoked after `onRestart()` and `onCreate()` methods just excluding `onStart()`? What is its purpose?

Why can't we live without `onStart()`. I still consider it as redundant (probably because don't understand its meaning completely).

Comment: Look here for the application lifecycle : http://d.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Comment: This stuff is easy.  Try explaining this WITH Fragments, now **that's** android programming for ya!

Comment: Answers below doesn't have actual code with explanation.[This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14021717/1911652) is code that explains it with fragment.

Answer (score 321, accepted):

> Why can't it be the onResume() is invoked after onRestart() and onCreate() methods just excluding onStart()? What is its purpose?

OK, as my first answer was pretty long I won't extend it further so let's try this...

```
public DriveToWorkActivity extends Activity
    implements onReachedGroceryStoreListener {
}

public GroceryStoreActivity extends Activity {}
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** I've deliberately left out the calls to things like `super.onCreate(...)` etc. This is pseudo-code so give me some artistic licence here. ;)

The methods for `DriveToWorkActivity` follow...

```
protected void onCreate(...) {
    openGarageDoor();
    unlockCarAndGetIn();
    closeCarDoorAndPutOnSeatBelt();
    putKeyInIgnition();
}

protected void onStart() {
    startEngine();
    changeRadioStation();
    switchOnLightsIfNeeded();
    switchOnWipersIfNeeded();
}

protected void onResume() {
    applyFootbrake();
    releaseHandbrake();
    putCarInGear();
    drive();
}

protected void onPause() {
    putCarInNeutral();
    applyHandbrake();
}

protected void onStop() {
    switchEveryThingOff();
    turnOffEngine();
    removeSeatBeltAndGetOutOfCar();
    lockCar();
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    enterOfficeBuilding();
}

protected void onReachedGroceryStore(...) {
    Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_GET_GROCERIES, ...,  this, GroceryStoreActivity.class);
}

protected void onRestart() {
    unlockCarAndGetIn();
    closeDoorAndPutOnSeatBelt();
    putKeyInIgnition();
}
```

OK, so it's another long one (sorry folks). But here's my explanation...

`onResume()` is when I start driving and `onPause()` is when I come to a temporary stop. So I drive then reach a red light so I pause...the light goes green and I resume. Another red light and I pause, then green so I resume. The `onPause() -> onResume() -> onPause() -> onResume()` loop is a tight one and occurs many times through my journey.

The loop from being stopped back through a restart (preparing to carry on my journey) to starting again is perhaps less common. In one case, I spot the Grocery Store and the `GroceryStoreActivity` is started (forcing my `DriveToWorkActivity` to the point of `onStop()`). When I return from the store, I go through `onRestart()` and `onStart()` then resume my journey.

I could put the code that's in `onStart()` into both `onCreate()` and `onRestart()` and not bother to override `onStart()` at all but the more that needs to be done between `onCreate() -> onResume()` and `onRestart() -> onResume()`, the more I'm duplicating things.

So, to requote once more...

> Why can't it be the onResume() is invoked after onRestart() and onCreate() methods just excluding onStart()?

If you don't override `onStart()` then this is effectively what happens. Although the `onStart()` method of `Activity` will be called implicitly, the effect in your code is effectively `onCreate() -> onResume()` or `onRestart() -> onResume()`.

Comment: This implies that both `onCreate()` and `onRestart()` would share a lot of common code, right?

Comment: @Dheeraj: No not necessarily. This is pseudo code and meant to just illustrate how each stage of the `Activity` life-cycle might be used. The creation stage `onCreate(...)` may well do a great deal when it comes to instantiating instance members (UI elements etc) but a 'restart' shouldn't need to do that. In reality many `Activities` don't really need to implement more than `onCreate(...)`, `onResume()` and `onPause()` the other methods are available for cases where you might need to do other things and the key is to understand where to put the code.

Comment: This is why I have come to hate the Android API compared to iOS and even WP7... Ive been making a game that runs on all three in C# and I have to say i'm rly disappointed with Google and Android.  They seem to be lacking in the Language / API design department.  I rly hope some other linux phone OS takes over, cuz I do vote for Open Source in general...

Comment: To me, having to call same function multiple times during these lifecycle events is a sign to bad design.

Comment: @Tim : OK, come up with a better design. How would you deal with a scenario on a mobile phone when somebody is using an app (your app) and they suddenly get a phone call? The app designer doesn't explicitly call the `Activity` life-cycle methods - it's the Android OS which does it and it does it very efficiently (assuming the app developer knows what they're doing and also codes efficiently). If you do a lot of Android development you'll realise why things work the way they do - it's not 100% perfect but it's pretty good.

Comment: Don't take me as a developer. I am generally speaking. It just comes to me that there must be even number of lifecycle functions because it is the natural behaviour of a cycle.

Comment: I think Nilesh's answer below is much clearer. The key difference between `onStart` and `onResume` is that of 'visibility' and 'user interaction'. This driving-a-car metaphor is confusing and not really helpful.

Comment: Nice analogy! Nice to see that onDestroy() doesn't have a method called driveOffTheCliff()

Answer (score 167):

Short answer:

We can't live without onStart because that is the state when the activity becomes "visible" to the user, but the user cant "interact" with it yet may be cause it's overlapped with some other small dialog. This ability to interact with the user is the one that differentiates onStart and onResume. Think of it as a person behind a glass door. You can see the person but you can't interact (talk/listen/shake hands) with him. OnResume is like the door opener after which you can begin the interaction.

Additionally onRestart() is the least understood one. We can ask the question as to why not directly go to onStart() or onResume() after onStop() instead of onRestart().
It becomes easier to understand if we note that onRestart() is partially equivalent to onCreate() if the creation part is omitted. Basically both states lead to onStart() (i.e the Activity becomes visible). So both the states have to "prepare" the stuff to be displayed. OnCreate has the additional responsibility to "create"  the stuff to be displayed

So their code structures might fit to something like:

```
onCreate()
{
     createNecessaryObjects();

     prepareObjectsForDisplay();
}


onRestart()
{
     prepareObjectsForDisplay();

}
```

The entire confusion is caused since Google chose non-intuitive names instead of something as follows:

```
onCreateAndPrepareToDisplay()   [instead of onCreate() ]
onPrepareToDisplay()            [instead of onRestart() ]
onVisible()                     [instead of onStart() ]
onBeginInteraction()            [instead of onResume() ]
onPauseInteraction()            [instead of onPause() ]
onInvisible()                   [instead of onStop]
onDestroy()                     [no change]
```

The Activity Diagram might be interpreted as:

[image: Android Activity Lifecycle]

Comment: When I explain it to students, I use maybeOnInvisible() instead of onStop(). And use maybeOnDestroy() instead of onDestroy(). These names work well as explanations I find. Thought, I wouldn't want Google to actually change to these names.

Comment: I like your suggested names, they help make _some_ sense of this part of the ridiculous Android API. I still have a question in general about the lifecycle. In all of the diagrams it shows there's a path from onPause directly to onResume. I don't think I've ever seen that path actually followed in any cases. It always takes the path from onStop to onStart. What would trigger the other path?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk why do you use maybe...()? Why "maybe"?

Comment: @DeweyVozel If your Activity gets covered by something else but not completely (it's still visible under that something but not in foreground) - then onPause -> OnResume is fired. I'd say http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html is a good example but I didn't check.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch, Do not rely on this old answer. Do not rely on my own comment either. The nuances of the Activity lifecycle have changed since then.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk could you explain what has changed? I tested this out and when a dialog or menu is opened in front of the activity (so the activity is partially covered) neither onPause() nor onResume() is fired. In fact, I couldn't reproduce any case where onResume() without onStart() is fired. This confuses me..

Comment: @Damnum, For the most recent explanation of the Activity lifecycle, I'd suggest you check out the intermediate Android Udacity course created by Google. It's free, assuming you click on the blue button to access its materials for free, and not the trial button (nor the nanodegree button). https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I watched Lesson 4A, Active and Visible Lifetimes. There the guy explained exactly that: When an activity is partly covered by a dialog, onPause() should be called. That just doesn't happen with my app. I open a list of menu items from the action bar and from there I open a dialog, all without triggering onPause().. Why is that?

Comment: @Damnum, I'd suggest you ask that question in the udacity forum related to the video you watched. But basically, I think it depends on the dialog being used, whether it's a dialog activity, or a dialog only.

Comment: So what method is active on an app when I press the home button and I'm in my app overview? onPause or/and onStop?

Answer (score 31):

`onStart()` called when the activity is becoming visible to the user.
`onResume()` called when the activity will start interacting with the user.
You may want to do different things in this cases.

See [this link](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for reference.

Answer (score 20):

`onResume()` is called:

1. after `onStart()`
2. when the `Activity` comes to the foreground.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle:
[image]

Answer (score 10):

The book "Hello, Android, Introducing Google's Mobile Development Platform" gives a nice explanation of the life cycle of android apps. Luckily they have the particular chapter online as an excerpt. See the graphic on page 39 in
http://media.pragprog.com/titles/eband3/concepts.pdf

By the way, this book is highly recommendable for android beginners!

Comment: Nice image and good book, but still it doesn't give an answer why do we really need onStart() method and what special things we can do in it we can't do in onResume().

Comment: onStart() is NOT called, if the app was paused. Your app is "paused" if another app gains the focus but does NOT obscure your app completely. So you may do different things in the "paused" state than you would do in "Stopped" state. Thus, you may do different things if your app is just "resumed" from paused state than you would do if your app is "started" from stopped state or from complete start. Does that help?

Answer (score 9):

**`onStart()`**

1. Called after onCreate(Bundle)  or after onRestart() followed by
   ***onResume()***.
2. you can register a BroadcastReceiver in `onStart()` to monitor changes
   that impact your UI, You have to unregister it in onStop()
3. Derived classes must call through to the super class's
   implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be
   thrown.

**`onResume()`**

1. Called after onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle), onRestart(), or
           onPause()
2. Begin animations, open exclusive-access devices (such as the camera)

**`onStart()`** normally dispatch work to a background thread, whose return values are:

- **START_STICKY** to automatically restart if killed, to keep it active.
- **`START_REDELIVER_INTENT`** for auto restart and retry if the service was killed before stopSelf().

**`onResume()`** is called by the OS after the device goes to sleep or after an Alert or other partial-screen child activity leaves a portion of the previous window visible so a method is need to re-initialize fields (within a try structure with a catch of exceptions).
 Such a situation does not cause `onStop()` to be invoked when the child closes.

### `onResume()` is called without **`onStart()`** when the activity resumes from the background

For More details you can visits [Android_activity_lifecycle_gotcha](http://steveliles.github.io/android_activity_lifecycle_gotcha.html) And [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: actually I gets onstop when my app goes to background

Answer (score 7):

A particularly feisty example is when you decide to show a managed Dialog from an Activity using `showDialog()`. If the user rotates the screen while the dialog is still open (we call this a "configuration change"), then the main Activity will go through all the ending lifecycle calls up untill `onDestroy()`, will be recreated, and go back up through the lifecycles. What you might not expect however, is that `onCreateDialog()` and `onPrepareDialog()` (the methods that are called when you do `showDialog()` and now again automatically to recreate the dialog - automatically since it is a managed dialog) are called **between** `onStart()` and `onResume()`. The pointe here is that the dialog does not cover the full screen and therefore leaves part of the main activity visible. It's a detail but it does matter!

Answer (score 7):

Hopefully a simple explanation : -

**onStart()** -> called when the activity becomes visible, but might not be in the foreground (e.g. an AlertFragment is on top or any other possible use case).

**onResume()** -> called when the activity is in the foreground, or the user can interact with the Activity.

Answer (score 4):

`onStart()` means `Activity` entered into visible state and layout is created but can't interact with this activity layout.

`Resume()` means now you can do interaction with activity layout.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this counts as an answer - but here is [YouTube Video From Google's Course](https://youtu.be/HLLDZs0MI54) (Developing Android Apps with Kotlin) that explains the difference.

- On Start is called when the activity becomes **visible**
- On Pause is called when the activity **loses focus** (like a dialog pops up)
- On Resume is called when the activity **gains focus** (like when a dialog disappears)

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are things that happen between the calls to onStart() and onResume(). Namely, onNewIntent(), which I've painfully found out.

If you are using the SINGLE_TOP flag, and you send some data to your activity, using intent extras, you will be able to access it only in onNewIntent(), which is called **after** onStart() and **before** onResume(). So usually, you will take the new (maybe only modified) data from the extras and set it to some class members, or use setIntent() to set the new intent as the original activity intent and process the data in onResume().

Answer (score 0):

Reference to http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

`onResume()` Called just before the activity starts interacting with the user. At this point the activity is at the top of the activity stack, with user input going to it.
Always followed by `onPause()`.

`onPause()` Called when the system is about to start resuming another activity. This method is typically used to commit unsaved changes to persistent data, stop animations and other things that may be consuming CPU, and so on. It should do whatever it does very quickly, because the next activity will not be resumed until it returns.
Followed either by `onResume()` if the activity returns back to the front, or by `onStop()` if it becomes invisible to the user.