# Android activity.onPause() then activity.onResume() restarts the app

Tags: android, onresume, onpause

I can successfully call activity.onPause() to pause the application.
But when i call activity.onResume() the application restarts.

Is there a way to avoid this ?

**Edited**

I actually want to pause my application using a pause button

Comment: You don't have to call onPause() manually, it will be called automatically once your activity goes in bg. Please post your code, then only we can help you to find the answer.

Comment: You are Not supposed to call these methods, android system calls them.

Comment: Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle If there's only one document you want to read on android, read this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should never call methods of the `Activity` life cycle by yourself! So no call to `onPause()` `onResume()` `onDestroy()` `onCreate()` `onStop()` or `onStart()`.

Edit to fit your edited question:

You should pause your game, not the Activity. You must have a thread where you work your game logic. That thread needs to be paused, not the game. So consider working on a pause logic there.

Comment: Almost same reply at the same time :P :D

Comment: indeed :) You should have posted that as an answer, too

Comment: I thought, If I post this as an answer, user's may downvote it, since it's more like a comment. But I should have done that, at least I would have earned some reps. :P :)

Comment: so how to pause an app and resume it?

Comment: Again,you don't have to worry about pausing an app and resume it. Android OS will handle it.

Comment: lets say, there you are playing a game! now you have to pause it in the middle! is it possible?

Comment: Consider using [DialogBox](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: @Dnu_12, you can save your application state by overriding the onSaveInstanceState() method, and restore it by overriding onRestoreInstanceState()

Comment: You should pause your game, not the Activity. You must have a thread where you work your game logic. That thread needs to be paused, not the game. So consider working on a pause logic there.

Comment: yes Warren!
Thanks!
now I understand!
I have a thread for the game logic, I'm pausing it, and it working fine,
I have some part of the logic running in the onDraw method as well, which I guess I have to transfer to the game logic thread,

I think you should post the last comment as a separate answer for me to tick it!

Comment: for later use, I merged my comment into the answer. Glad we could help.

Answer (score 1):

As I can guess no there isn't. All activites are using following flow:
http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

You should save activity state and than resume it.

And as mentioned above you shouldn't call it yourself... just override/implement it and let Android do the job.

Comment: Hi!
How can I save the activity and resume it?

Comment: You can use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState(). Check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android

Comment: That seems to work!
But if i have lots of data to be passed that will be a problem for me :(

Comment: Basically we are using it to store activity state, values from edit test's and so on... from activity just for the time when it'll not be used... for other puropses you should use Sqlite database. What kind of data you man by "lots"??

Comment: It seems that i have misunderstood onPause and onResume
What i actually wanted to do is to pause my app with a button!
it seems calling onPause should not be done for that purpose,,
or is it the one?

Comment: What you mean by "pause application"? You want to put it into background?

Comment: No, Robert! lets say a user is playing a game and he want to pause it!
well I did this by pausing the logic thread,

But I have some of the logic part in my onDraw method which I'm now going to transfer to the logic thread as well,,

it will do what I wanted,,

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

see Activity  life cycle like  as

```
protected void onCreate(...) {
   // do Your work here
}

protected void onStart() {
   //       do Your work here
}

protected void onResume() {
        //  do Your work here
}

protected void onPause() {
               //  do Your work here
}

protected void onStop() {
               //  do Your work here
}

protected void onDestroy() {
              //  do Your work here
}



protected void onRestart() {
               //  do Your work here
}
```

under stood this method and You should save activity state and than resume it.

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553605/difference-between-onstart-and-onresume

Comment: it seems that the app is been paused by the OS and if i want to add a pause button to pause the app (what i wanted to do) i should not call onPause() within on click pause button?