# How to skip and call an activity in the back stack

Tags: android, back-stack

Assume I have 2 activities A  and B. A is the main activity and set as singleTask so only one instance will be created.

Activity B can be instantiated many times. In onPause() in Activity B, I am calling activity A.

If I have 2 instances of activity B, then the first instance will call its onPause(), so the second instance will close quickly, because the first instance of activity B will call the instance of A and it will clear all activities and come to front.

I want to avoid that flow, instead the last instance of activity B should call instance of activity A.

How to do that?

Comment: `then the first instance will call its onPause(),` this sounds wrong. How do you achieve this in code?

Comment: when a new instance(second one) of activity B is created the first instance of activity B will go to background. (there it calls onPause())

Comment: Figured. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12459408/2413303