# Fragment ViewState restored in onStart?

Tags: android

When orientation changes, fragment `viewState` restored only in `onStart`. 
After `onAttach`, `onCreateView`, `onViewCreated` and `onActivityCreated` and even after `onCreate`.
Why? This is too late.

I need to populate db query results to ListView based on some TextView value. Currently i try to do this in `onViewCreated`. But view state isn't restored at this step.

Can i force restore early?
Or how to overcome this problem? 
Any ideas, please.

PS: i use actionbarsherlock and dependent android support-v4 r7 library

PS2: if i will load data in `onStart` then it will do additional queries when fragment is resumed after `onStop` (i can solve this by adding some boolean `isLoaded` - but this isn't best solution).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Android API >= 17 (Android 4.2 Jelly Beans) there is a method:
`public void onViewStateRestored (Bundle savedInstanceState)`

which is called before `onStart()` and after `onActivityCreated()` as mentioned in [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewStateRestored%28android.os.Bundle%29).

In Android API < 17 there is no such method. But there are two solutions:

1. Don't rely on view state while initializing `Fragment` and save all required initialization state as `Fragment` state (i.e. override `Fragment#onSaveInstanceState()`). Later you can restore fragment state in `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()`.
2. Perform initialization in `onStart()` as specified in question.

Answer (score 4):

[EDIT 1 - - - - - - -]

// Check to see if the Fragment back stack has been populated

// If not, create and populate the layout.

// so your fragment wont recreated

```
  YourFragment yourFragment = (YourFragment )fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

  if (yourFragment == null) {
       FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction(); 
       ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new YourFragment ());       
       ft.commit();
  }
```

[EDIT 1 - - - - - - -]

[image]

```
/**
 * Listing 4-4: Fragment skeleton code
 * Listing 4-5: Fragment lifecycle event handlers
 */
package com.paad.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MySkeletonFragment extends Fragment {

  // Called when the Fragment is attached to its parent Activity.
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Get a reference to the parent Activity.
  }

  // Called to do the initial creation of the Fragment.
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Initialize the Fragment.
  }

  // Called once the Fragment has been created in order for it to
  // create its user interface.
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Create, or inflate the Fragment's UI, and return it. 
    // If this Fragment has no UI then return null.
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
  }



  // Called once the parent Activity and the Fragment's UI have 
  // been created.
  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Complete the Fragment initialization Ğ particularly anything
    // that requires the parent Activity to be initialized or the 
    // Fragment's view to be fully inflated.
  }

  // Called at the start of the visible lifetime.
  @Override
  public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    // Apply any required UI change now that the Fragment is visible.
  }

  // Called at the start of the active lifetime.
  @Override
  public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // Resume any paused UI updates, threads, or processes required
    // by the Fragment but suspended when it became inactive.
  }

  // Called at the end of the active lifetime.
  @Override
  public void onPause(){
    // Suspend UI updates, threads, or CPU intensive processes
    // that don't need to be updated when the Activity isn't
    // the active foreground activity.
    // Persist all edits or state changes
    // as after this call the process is likely to be killed.
    super.onPause();
  }

  // Called to save UI state changes at the
  // end of the active lifecycle.
  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle will be passed to onCreate, onCreateView, and
    // onCreateView if the parent Activity is killed and restarted.
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  }

  // Called at the end of the visible lifetime.
  @Override
  public void onStop(){
    // Suspend remaining UI updates, threads, or processing
    // that aren't required when the Fragment isn't visible.
    super.onStop();
  }

  // Called when the Fragment's View has been detached.
  @Override
  public void onDestroyView() {
    // Clean up resources related to the View.
    super.onDestroyView();
  }

  // Called at the end of the full lifetime.
  @Override
  public void onDestroy(){
    // Clean up any resources including ending threads,
    // closing database connections etc.
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  // Called when the Fragment has been detached from its parent Activity.
  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
  }
}
```

> source : Professional Android Development 4 - Reto Meier

Comment: in `onAttach` view doesn't exists.
As specified in ur comment in `onActivityCreated` view exists, but saved fragment view state isn't restored yet.

Comment: Yes view is created onCreateView.

Comment: LayoutView returned from onCreateView isn't initialized and contains initial values. I need restored values at the moment when orientation changes.

Comment: Do you need to change the value with every orientation change ?

Comment: No, i need to reload data from database when orientation changes. But query requires `search` string parameter. I take this `search` parameter from TextView#getValue(), but after orientation change fragment is recreated and TextView value is lost. It will be restored later, only in `onStart`.

Comment: Pls look at the edited answer, if you check Fragment back stack has been populated, it will solve your problem.

Comment: Not correct. Fragment (and whole containing activity) is always recreated on orientation change unless you call `setRetainInstance(true)` or set `android:configChanges="orientation"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Pls, look at this simple example, https://dl.dropbox.com/u/68130108/FragmentTest.rar

Comment: Sorry, man. Didn't find it useful. In attached example you have one EditText. When orientation will change its value will be lost... Until `DetailsFragment#onStart`.   
    DetailsFragment detailsFragment = (DetailsFragment)      fm.findFragmentById(R.id.details_container);
if (detailsFragment != null)
{
  // next expression will always be true
((EditText)detailsFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().equals("");

Comment: Ok, i am sorry it didnt help to you :)

Comment: To prevent data loss on orientation change you just have to change 1 line in the manifest :/

Answer (score 0):

You can always handle orientation changes yourself with `onConfigurationChanged()`. See a nice example here http://alexfu.tumblr.com/post/13926762386/android-dev-handling-fragment-recreation-manually