# Android mediaplayer singleton service won't stop playing

Tags: android, service, singleton, android-mediaplayer

I need to have background music in all my activities. It should stop when the application is not foreground. As I'm developing for 2.3 I can't use the ActivityLifeCycleCallBacks class. I implemented the solution at [Checking if an Android application is running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background/5862048#5862048) and then decided to make the mediaplayer a singleton and use it in a service.

Everything works fine and if I press home, select quit from the menu or I make the application go background any way the sound stops but... **after some random time when I'm doing something else or even when the screen is turned off the music will start again out of the blue. Even if I kill the application from task manager the will start again later again.**

This is my first singleton and my first time playing with service so I guess I'm missing something really basic. I think I'm closing the service but apparently I'm not.
Here is the code:

PlayAudio.java

```
import ...
public class PlayAudio extends Service{
    private static final Intent Intent = null;
    MediaPlayer objPlayer;
    private int length = 0;
    boolean mIsPlayerRelease = true;
    private static PlayAudio uniqueIstance; //the singleton
    static PlayAudio mService;
    static boolean mBound = false; // boolean to check if the service containing this singleton is binded to some activity
    public static boolean activityVisible; // boolean to check if the activity using the player is foreground or not

//My attempt to make a singleton
public static PlayAudio getUniqueIstance(){
    if (uniqueIstance == null) {
        uniqueIstance = new PlayAudio();
    }
    return uniqueIstance;
}
public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
    return activityVisible;
  }  

  public static void activityResumed() {
    activityVisible = true;
  }

  public static void activityPaused() {
    activityVisible = false;
  }
static public ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {// helper for the activity

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
public static Intent createIntent (Context context) { //helper for the activity using the player
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PlayAudio.class);
    return intent;
}
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    PlayAudio getService() {
        // Return this instance so clients can call public methods
        return PlayAudio.this;
    }
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "Service Started!");
    objPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.kickstarterreduced);
    objPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mIsPlayerRelease = false;
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    objPlayer.start();
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "Media Player started!");
    if(objPlayer.isLooping() != true){
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Problem in Playing Audio");
    }
    return 1;
}

public void onStop(){
    objPlayer.setLooping(false);
    objPlayer.stop();
    objPlayer.release();
    mIsPlayerRelease = true;
}

public void onPause(){
    if(objPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        objPlayer.pause();
        length=objPlayer.getCurrentPosition(); // save the position in order to be able to resume from here
    }   
}
public void resumeMusic() // if length is 0 the player just start from zero
{   if (mIsPlayerRelease == true) {
    objPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.kickstarterreduced);
    mIsPlayerRelease = false;
}
    if(objPlayer.isPlaying()==false )
    {
        if (length != 0) objPlayer.seekTo(length);
        objPlayer.start();
    }
}

}
```

And this are the methods I have implemented in every activity's class

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
PlayAudio playerIstanced;
public static boolean activityVisible;
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
   }
@Override
public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       playerIstanced= PlayAudio.getUniqueIstance(); //call singleton
       bindService(PlayAudio.createIntent(this), playerIstanced.mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); // create the service
       if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("sound", true) == true) {// if sound is enabled in option it will start the service
           startService(PlayAudio.createIntent(this));
           playerIstanced.mService.activityResumed();
           if (playerIstanced.mBound == true) {
           playerIstanced.mService.resumeMusic();
           }
       }

   }
   @Override
   public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       playerIstanced.mService.activityPaused();
       final Handler handler = new Handler();
       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
           //If the phone lags when changing activity (between onPause() and the other activity onResume() the music won't stop. If after 500ms onResume() is not called it means the activity went background...Am I messing with service here?
             if (playerIstanced.mService.isActivityVisible() != true) {
                 playerIstanced.mService.onPause();
             }
         }
       }, 500);

}
   @Override
   public void onStop(){
       super.onStop();
       // Unbind from the service
       if (playerIstanced.mService.mBound) {
           playerIstanced.mService.mBound = false;
           unbindService(playerIstanced.mService.mConnection);

       }
   }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop music automatically when user exit from app

This part has to be in EVERY activity's onPause:

```
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
                if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
                  ComponentName topActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity; 
                  if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                   StopPlayer();
                    Toast.makeText(xYourClassNamex.this, "YOU LEFT YOUR APP. MUSIC STOP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                }
      }
```

This part has to be in EVERY activity's onResume:

Play music automatically when user resume the app

```
Public void onResume()
    {
       super.onResume();
     StartPlayer();
    }
```

Hope it helps!!
You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094878/how-to-play-mp3-continuosly-when-application-starts-and-stop-when-user-close-app/18094911#18094911) according to this topic may it will sove your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I still can't properly understand what does your code do but it works. Instead of StopPlayer() I decided to pause it and stop it only when the activity calls onStop() on itself. If you have some times would you bother explaining line by line your solution? I tried googling a bit but I'm still lost.

Comment: @pinolo,here i am looking for front Activity. If My App screen is not on Front that means User left from My App. I can get this from ActivityManager.Which will give the Running Task list.I can get the front Activity from `taskInfo.get(0).topActivity`. then i just compare it to my app's Activity. If its not match then App is closed. Hope you get it!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually stop the service using Context.stopService() or stopSelf(). See the **Service Lifecycle** section of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html.

> **Service Lifecycle**
>
> There are two reasons that a service can be run by the system. If someone calls Context.startService() then the system will retrieve the service (creating it and calling its onCreate() method if needed) and then call its onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method with the arguments supplied by the client. The service will at this point continue running until Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called. Note that multiple calls to Context.startService() do not nest (though they do result in multiple corresponding calls to onStartCommand()), so no matter how many times it is started a service will be stopped once Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called; however, services can use their stopSelf(int) method to ensure the service is not stopped until started intents have been processed.

I believe you can simply put playerIstanced.stopSelf() in the onStop() call of each activity.

My understanding is that the service continues to run quietly after your application stops. After a while the system kills the service to free up resources, and then after a while more when resources are available it restarts the service. When the service restarts its onResume() is called and the music begins playing.

Comment: I decided to implement your solution and @geet 's solution too. in onStop() I implemented         if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }

Answer (score 0):

it helped me stop the mediaplayer.
Use Handler(getMainLooper()) to start and stop MediaPlayer.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
   mediaPlayer.start();
}
});

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
     mediaPlayer.stop();
}
}
, 30 * 1000);
```