# stopping mediaplayer sound by pressing back or home button

Tags: java, android, audio, switch-statement

I got the switch and new layout to work, thank you everyone. One last question though. I would like the music to stop playing if the user presses the back or home button. This is the code, I do not know what I am missing.

```
package com.androidsleepmachine.gamble;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Ocean extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
 public static final Integer[] TIME_IN_MINUTES = { 30, 45, 60, 180, 360 };
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public Handler handler = new Handler();
public Button button1;
public Spinner spinner1;

// Initialize the activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.ocean);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,  
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TIME_IN_MINUTES);          
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);          
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter); 
}

// Play the sound and start the timer
private void playSound(int resourceId) {
    // Cleanup any previous sound files
    cleanup();
    // Create a new media player instance and start it
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    // Create the timer to stop the sound after x number of milliseconds
    int selectedTime = TIME_IN_MINUTES[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()];
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, selectedTime * 60 * 1000);
}

// Handle button callback
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            playSound(R.raw.ocean_birds);
            break;
    }
}

// Stop the sound and cleanup the media player
public void cleanup() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
    // Cancel any previously running tasks
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

// Runnable task used by the handler to stop the sound
public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        cleanup();
    }
};
}
```

Logcat

```
09-18 00:28:59.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1627): android.app.SuperNotCalledException:  
Activity {com.androidsleepmachine.gamble/com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Ship} did not 
call through to super.onStop()
09-18 00:28:59.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at 
android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5148)
09-18 00:28:59.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3232)
09-18 00:28:59.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at   
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 00:28:59.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-18 00:28:59.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-18 00:28:59.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at     
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check is user close the App or just switching to another Activity.
You can check my Answers for that

[Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669541/android-mediaplayer-singleton-service-wont-stop-playing/18669672#18669672)

[Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094878/how-to-play-mp3-continuosly-when-application-starts-and-stop-when-user-close-app/18094911#18094911)

Hope it helps!!

**EDIT**

Check this both method in your `ship` class.

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "App stopped");

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "App destoryed");

        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: I put in   protected void onStop()
  {
    if (this.mediaPlayer != null)
      this.mediaPlayer.stop();
  }                                                                 
everything works fine and it stops the music when the back button is pressed but as soon as it goes back one screen it force closes.

Comment: `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` Change in Oncreate()

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                     That still force closes

Comment: Check onStop method of your Ship class.u can post your updated code of that class also.

Comment: Check my edit answer. make sure that all your class contains that methods.

Answer (score -2):

use on key up

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            stop sound!
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: stop sound! doesnt work, what should the stop sound! be in reference to my code?

Comment: and what is the line 'stop sound!' should be?
when we didn't have View Object to disable sound effect?

Comment: Lol `stop sound!`, this was of great help sir