# Android app: onResume() and onStart()

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have read documentation on `onResume()` and `onStart()` but one thing I'm still not cleared is under what scenario does `onResume()` get called **without** `onStart()` being called before it?

Comment: I think this answer will help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553605/difference-between-onstart-and-onresume

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) diagram, it's self explanatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please Refer to the [Android Activity Lifecycle Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

`onStart` is called when your application first starts.

If the user click the home button, or another app takes focus, `onPause` will be called.

If the activity regains focus, while stil running on the device, `onResume` will be called, and `onCreate` will NOT be called again.

If the user uses the activity manager to close the application, and then relaunches it, `onCreate` will be called again.

Note, every time `onCreate` is called, `onResume` is also called.

[image: Lifecycle]

Answer (score 1):

Check below chart:

[image: Activity lifecycle]

In case your activity is visible but not active - onPause will be called, and then when you return to this Activity - onResume

Answer (score 1):

One such scenario where `onResume()` is called without `onStart()` being called is change of Focus. Think about a dialog popping up on the screen while you're using the application. This is the case when `onPause()` is called, followed by `onResume()` after dismissal of dialog.

Answer (score 0):

onStart() gets called once each time the app is launched and is actually called after oncreate()

onResume() gets called instead if the app is already running, just in the background.

if you use onPause(), on Resume will likely get called when you bring your app up again, basically onResume() is a reusable onStart() for when the app is already started.

onResume can sometimes be called when switching activities, onStart only gets called when creating one.

Answer (score 0):

`onResume()` is called without `onStart()` when the activity resumes from the background.