# Detect when an external app runs onCreate, onStart, onResume in Android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I wanted to ask you if someone knows how to detect when an external app runs one of this methods. I'm working with some classmates in a project where we want to examinate the response time of other applications. The idea is to measure the time between the run of each method to get an aproximation of the response time when opening the app.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: if you read the documentation it will tell you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStart() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()

Comment: are you looking for someone to copy/paste the documentation for you? what more information can you expect than what is very well documented in the doc linked by @tyczj ? (if there is a particular point that is unclear, you need to be more specific about it.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between onStart() and onResume()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553605/difference-between-onstart-and-onresume)

Comment: Sorry, i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the android's application lifecycle diagram.

`onStart()` is called when an Activity is created(new activity created when user gets to it) or restarted(when a backgrounded activity comes back).

`onResume()` is called when an activity is started and when it cames back from being paused.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`onStart` is called after a fully obscured activity comes to foreground (or when it first comes to foreground).

`onResume` is called after `onStart` and it is also called after a partially obscured activity comes to foreground. That is, `onResume` is called after a fully or a partially obscured activity comes to foregorund.

When a partially obscured activity comes to foregound `onStart` does not get called.

Answer (score 1):

We can't live without onStart because that is the state when the activity becomes "visible" to the user, but the user cant "interact" with it yet may be cause it's overlapped with some other small dialog. This ability to interact with the user is the one that differentiates onStart and onResume. Think of it as a person behind a glass door. You can see the person but you can't interact (talk/listen/shake hands) with him. OnResume is like the door opener after which you can begin the interaction.

this question is answered here, there are very good examples

[onresume and onStart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9113112/2367851)

Comment: Why we can live without onStart we can set up everything in onCreate