# android activity lifecycle callbacks and states

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

Please, help me understand activity lyfecycle more deeply. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks
They say:

> The foreground lifetime of an activity happens between the call to
>   onResume() and the call to onPause().

Does this mean, that activity becomes resumed in some moment after onResume() is called, or after onResume() completely  finished it's work?
Similar question about visible state and onStart.
And if the second is right (method completely  finished it's work), then super.method() or overriden by me in activity class?

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // is it now "resumed" after super.onResume()?
}
```

Comment: check this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/a/4653671/1034849

Answer (score 1):

"The foreground lifetime of an activity" referes to the time it is directly being shown to the user. It also implies at the moment its process has maximun priority on the Android process priority ladder. You should read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html
Furthermore, `onResume()`, `onPause()`... are just hooks where you should insert code that needs to be executed on that specific moment of the activity lifcycle.

Answer (score 0):

> > The foreground lifetime of an activity happens between the call to onResume() and the call to onPause().
>
> Does this mean, that activity becomes resumed in some moment after onResume() is called, or after onResume() completely finished it's work?

Technically speaking, the `Activity` is in a state of being resumed before `onResume()` is called but the option for you to override the `onResume()` method allows you to fine-tune what needs to be done before the `Activity` enters the 'running' state. In other words, from the point of view of the OS, the `Activity` is resumed, then `onResume()` is called and, finally, from the point of view of your own individual app, resuming the `Activity` is complete when `onResume()` is complete and the `Activity` is running.

> Similar question about visible state and onStart. And if the second is right (method completely finished it's work), then super.method() or overriden by me in activity class?

Again, the same logic applies - the OS goes through what it needs to do to start the `Activity` then calls `onStart()` for you to customise the starting stage of your `Activity`. The OS considers the `Activity` to have started before it calls `onStart()` but from your app's perspective, it hasn't completely become started until any code you have in your overridden `onStart()` method.