# Android Studio activity - using onCreate(), onResume() etc

Tags: java, android, activity-lifecycle

So, I have an activity where the user can view words he has collected. If a entered word exists and uses only the available letters then he/she will be given a score which appears in a textView.

Issues:

- When the user exits the activity (e.g. goes to collect more letters) and then goes back to the activity where he enters words, the current score is no longer there and the all the letters he had collected are back in there even if has used them. I understand that this issue is because the activity gets reset each time the user leaves it and enters it. I just don't quite understand how to use the onCreate, onResume, onPause methods.
- It seems the user can only enter one word. when I try to enter another word after having entered the first word, nothing happens even though he has letters for that word available.

My code has this structure currently,

```
public class calculateScoreActivity extends AppcompactActivity{
    //initialise variables to be used
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //set variables to textViews etc
        //then go to method buttonClicked()
}

public void buttonClicked(){
    //if the button is pressed and user input is correct go to:
    updateDictionary()
    calculateScore()
}

public void updateDictionary(){
    //remove letters used in the word the user inputted
}

public void calculateScore(){
    //calculate the user score
}
```

Am I correct in writing these methods outside the onCreate? Where and how would I use onPause and onResume so that the user can pick up from where he left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Activity Life Cycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Read this chart. Use the methods within the range that you are, I usually do all my static setups (views e.t.c) in onCreate() and then use the other methods of the life cycle when needed.

OnPause would be before you pass to the activity that's coming to the foreground and onResume will be activated when you get again to this activity.

Comment: so would I pass all my methods for calculating score, checking the words etc in lets say onResume or onStart?

Comment: if you exit the activity to get something in return use onResume, if you have exited the activity to navigate to it afterwards use onStart.

Comment: [Here's an answer to the difference between those two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553605/difference-between-onstart-and-onresume)